# Is there a way to inherit interface method annotation in Groovy? (possible glitch in @Delegate)

Tags: inheritance, methods, groovy, interface, annotations

My example is done with [Koshuke args4j's](http://args4j.kohsuke.org/) `@Option` annotation but the same apply for any other method annotation. Just to clarify, this annotation may be used with either field or setter.

It works as follows:

```
class AnOptionExample {
    @Option(name = '-text')
    String text
}
```

And the test case:

```
def 'recognises option from simple object'() {
    given:
    def options = new AnOptionExample()
    def parser = new CmdLineParser(options)

    when:
    parser.parseArgument('-text=whatever')

    then:
    options.text == 'whatever'
}
```

Now assuming I would like to annotate on the interface level and then re-use `@Option` definitions as well as have kind of multi-inheritance which would allow use of different interfaces for different option sets there we go (simplified example):

```
interface Credentials {
    @Option(name = '-username')
    void setUsername(String username)

    @Option(name = '-password')
    void setPassword(String username)

    String getUsername()

    String getPassword()
}

class CredentialsImpl implements Credentials {
    String username
    String password
}
```

Test case which shows a failure:

```
def 'does not recognise option from interface'() {
    given:
    def options = new CredentialsImpl()
    def parser = new CmdLineParser(options)

    when:
    parser.parseArgument('-username=John', '-password=qwerty123')

    then:
    def ex = thrown(CmdLineException)
    ex.message == '"-username=John" is not a valid option'
}
```

Well, method annotations of interface are not inherited. Fair enough - that's the Java way, but how about Groovy? Some hope is given by the following:

```
class SomeOptionsWithDelegate {
    @Delegate(methodAnnotations = true)
    final Credentials credentials = new CredentialsImpl()

    @Option(name = '-url')
    String url
}
```

And the test case which shows something strange:

```
def 'does recognise option from interface via @Delegate'() {
    given:
    def options = new SomeOptionsWithDelegate()
    def parser = new CmdLineParser(options)

    when:
    parser.parseArgument('-username=John', '-password=qwerty123', '-url=http://auth.plop.com')

    then:
    with(options) {
        username == 'John'
        password == 'qwerty123'
        url == 'http://auth.plop.com'
    }
}
```

Surprisingly `@Delegate(methodAnnotations = true)` works despite the fact that the object instance to which delegation is done has no annotations - just the `Credentials` interface has them. And there is no method annotation inheritance... oh wait, actually that's the point. It seems to be a glitch. Why `@Delegate` is able to pick-up those annotations stated on the interface level if they are not inherited by `CredentialsImpl`?

On the other hand I would like to have exactly such a behaviour as a feature so I wouldn't need to use delegation here, instead go like:

```
@InheritInterfaceMethodAnnotations
class SomeOptionsViaInterface implements Credentials {
    String username
    String password

    @Option(name = '-url')
    String url
}
```

Clearly relevant test case for the above example would have failed the same way as for the 2nd example. Thus the question: is there anything like the imaginary annotation I made up -  `@InheritInterfaceMethodAnnotations` available?
It is possible to implement considering `@Delegate` glitch. As it seems to be useful feature, perhaps someone has already done it. If not, any advice how to implement it on my own is welcome.

Answer (score 0):

You should look into [traits](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/documentation/core-traits.html) they are the Groovy way of handling situations like this. It's sort of like extending a class, but you can do it with as many traits as you want. There are rules for method overlap, and ways to determine which trait's method to call.  Your annotations should work as well.

```
trait Credentials {
    String username

    @Option(name = '-username')
    void setUsername(String aUsername){
        username = aUsername}

    @Option(name = '-password')
    abstract void setPassword(String username)

    String getUsername() {return username}

    abstract String getPassword()
}

class CredentialsImpl implements Credentials {
    String password

    @Option(name = '-password')
    void setPassword(String password){ this.password = password}
    String getPassword() { password }
}
```

They can be added to objects at runtime as well

```
def 'does recognise option from interface via @Delegate'() {
    given:
        def parser = new CmdLineParser(new Object() as Credentials )

    when:
        parser.parseArgument('-username=John', '-password=qwerty123', '-url=http://auth.plop.com')

    then:
    with(options) {
        username == 'John'
        password == 'qwerty123'
        url == 'http://auth.plop.com'
    }
  }
```

Comment: Oh, I'm pretty sure I was experimenting with traits and I had the same exact result as with interfaces. I'll have look again though, thanks.